# socket Transport close when send message nestjs angular

Tags: angular, socket.io, nestjs

[enter image description here][1]
Due to a mutilple push message in an array, my socket disconnects with a transport close error

User can send  6 or 7 messages when the 8th is send and  push it into my array the socket connection disconnects

```
[enter image description here][2]
     getMessage(): void {
        this.chatService.getNewMessage().subscribe((value) => {
          this.getNewMessage(value);
        });
      }
    
      getNewMessage(value: Message): void {
        value.idSender = value.userSender.id;
        value.idReciever = value.userReceiver.id;
        const us = this.users.find(val => {
          return val.id === value.userSender.id
        });
        if (us) {
          // there i push the message
          us.messageConversation.push(value);
        }
      }


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlAd5.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5tCw.png
```

Answer (score 1):

I just realized that the object that I sent from the client(Angular) to the server(NestJS)  with socket.io was very big(69912 characters),
So with several sends of a heavy object it leads to the disconnection of the socket with the reason: `transport close`.

It might help.
Get size of a JavaScript object in Bytes.
[npm i object-sizeof](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-sizeof)

```
var sizeof = require('object-sizeof')
  
// 2B per character, 6 chars total => 12B
console.log(sizeof({abc: 'def'}))
```